# Как подключить Postgresql, к проекту на Unity?

Tags: unity3d, postgresql, visual-studio-code

Я за пару дней просмотрел кучу форумов и материалов по этой теме, но так и не нашёл как это сделать. Не получается собрать проект с подключённым Postgresql .
Читал [тут](https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-npgsql-dll-to-access-postgresql-server.7373/).
Релиз [npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases) , есть ещё [тут](https://github.com/mguillemot/UnityNpgsql). Как эти пользоваться я не совсем понимаю. Может кто подключал Postgresql к Unity? Объясните по шагам как это сделать.

Comment: Берете С библиотеку для работы с постгре, дергаете ее из С++ кода, который дергаете из юнити. Процесс слабо отличается от работы с другими нативными библиотеками.

Comment: @user7860670 Не чего не понял . Тем кому и просто, в определённых вопросах, не задают их. Я спросил потому что не получается.

Comment: Зачем переводить заголовок на английский? У нас русскоязычный сайт.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Думал охватить более широкую аудиторию

Comment: Тогда уж лучше перепостить на https://stackoverflow.com/ и перевести на английский вообще все.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Меня там забанили хз на какой срок . За то что часто удалял свои вопросы

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Скорее за то, что их минусили. :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105355/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-holyblackcat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не где нет хорошего мануала для того чтоб подружить Unity и Postgresql решил написать тут (у меня Windows 10 , Postgresql 9.4.26, Unity_2019.3.3f1) :

1 Чтоб не вылетали ошибки типа:

```
  Assembly 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll' will not be loaded due to errors: Reference has errors 'Npgsql'
  PrecompiledAssemblyException: Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name Npgsql.resources.dll included for the current platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per platform. Assembly paths: Assets/Plugins/es/Npgsql.resources.dll, Assets/Plugins/zh-CN/Npgsql.resources.dll, Assets/Plugins/de/Npgsql.resources.dll, Assets/Plugins/ja/Npgsql.resources.dll, Assets/Plugins/fr/Npgs
```

После установки [Postgresql](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) добавьте в переменные среды его:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня версия Postgresql 9.4.26 .

2 Этап [скомпилировать](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql) или с помощью visual studio 2019 достать нужную библиотеку Npgsql.dll. Для этого в visual studio 2019 воспользуйтесь NuGet:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для меня подошла Npgsql.2.2.7 . После установки она появиться в паке H:\Unity\postgres\Packages\Npgsql.2.2.7\lib\net20 ту в папке lib есть папки net20,net35,net40,net45 я так понял надо выбирать в зависимости от того какой Api Compatibility Level* стоит у вас, у меня: `.NET Standard 2.0` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Берёте из папке именно тот Npgsql.dll который нужен вам и создаёте в папке Assets(у меня она по пути H:\Unity\postgres\Assets) папку Plugins . Помещаете туда Npgsql.dll .
Вуаля теперь у вас есть все чтоб подключиться к Postgresql.

3 Этап пишете класс Test у меня она выглядит так :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
//using System.Data;   ## REMOVE THIS
using Npgsql;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test
{
    public static void postgres()
    {
        string connectionString =
            "Port = 5433;"+
            "Server=localhost;" +
            "Database=db_eco;" +
            "User ID=postgres;" +
            "Password=postgres;";
        // IDbConnection dbcon; ## CHANGE THIS TO
        NpgsqlConnection dbcon;

        dbcon = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        dbcon.Open();
        //IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();## CHANGE THIS TO
        NpgsqlCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        // requires a table to be created named employee
        // with columns firstname and lastname
        // such as,
        //        CREATE TABLE employee (
        //           firstname varchar(32),
        //           lastname varchar(32));
        string sql =
            "SELECT vendor, product " +
            "FROM visualinspectiondata.devices";
        dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
        //IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader(); ## CHANGE THIS TO
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            //string FirstName = (string)reader.GetString(0); 
            string LastName = (reader.IsDBNull(1)) ? "NULL" : reader.GetString(1).ToString();
            //string LastName = (string)reader.GetString(1);
            Debug.Log("Name: " + " " + LastName);
            //Console.WriteLine();
        }
        // clean up
        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose();
        dbcmd = null;
        dbcon.Close();
        dbcon = null;
    }
}
```

Смотрите что в консоле , что в базе :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем все это нужно? Ну вы подключили у себя на машине таким шаманским способом, а что делать с другими пользователями?

Comment: @ThisMan не понял вопроса ? С какими другими пользователями ? Я описал самый просто способ, чтоб прикрутить Postgresql к проекту на Unity

Comment: @ThisMan Если в Игру будут играть в сети ... Выкладываете бд в сеть и меняете только connectionString ... вот и всё

Comment: @ThisMan приимущество моего способа, то что не надо возиться с библиотекой Npgsql.dll . Я так до сих пор и не понял как её собрать, куча ошибок , в моей версии Unity вылетает до 1000